# ext install command hangs and never shows list of available extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install an extension for vs code, but it hangs and never shows the drop down list. I have also checked the common question's section on this [site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery). It says that:

> A: This could be due to an incomplete uninstall of an extension which
>   left some extension files under your .vscode/extensions folder.
>   Navigate to .vscode/extensions and see if there is an extension folder
>   (named for the publisher and extension as publisher.extension) for a
>   recently deleted extension. Delete that folder and restart VS Code.

But the folder is empty.

Comment: Do you maybe sit behind a proxy? Support for proxies and extensions will come in our December release.

Comment: I am having this same issue. Just sits there and never completes. No Proxy. .vscode/extensions is empty

Comment: @BenjaminPasero I've installed VS Code 1.0.0 on Windows 10 with a proxy that authenticates with the Windows Domain Account. Added a "http.proxy" entry to user settings, but I still get nothing (no list, nothing gets installed). How do I get this to work. (my question would be a duplicate of Sirwan's).

Comment: Issues should be filed against our issue tracker https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues